# Is my answer for this quadratic graph question correct?

Tags: quadratics

There is a question in my maths exercises textbook that I have got a different answer than the one given in my textbook.

**The question is :-**

For the following graph of the quadratic equation
$$ y = ax^2 + bx + c $$
is the product abc is negative?

[image]

**So my answer is:-**

In the figure (a), the parabola is downward so  $$ a < 0 $$ 
Since the parabola intersects the y-axis at a negative point, $$ c < 0$$
Since the x-vertex is negative
$$ \frac{-b}{2a} < 0 $$
$$ -b < 0$$
$$ b > 0 $$
As 'a' is negative, 'b' is positive and 'c' is negative, their product abc must be positive. However the textbook says that the product is negative. Is it a printing mistake or is my answer wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes the answer in the textbook is that abc is negative. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only error in your reasoning is when you said $a,c<0$ and $\frac{-b}{2a}<0$ implies $-b<0$ - it should be $-b>0$, from which $b<0$. Then $a,b,c<0$ implies $abc<0$.

When you multiply or divide both sides of an inequality by a negative number, the inequality sign flips.